# Unity admob doesn't show ads anymore

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, admob

My game used to show banner ads. Then I add rewarded ad unit. But I haven't updated it yet on app markets, there are still the old versions. When I run it on my test device which is registered on Admob, debug logcat says: Ad failed to load:3, no ad config. And after run the new version on my test device, my game doesn't show any ads from any device, even with the old version which is on the app markets. It's too weird, how does it effect to released version? I didn't touch it.. The codes are the same with the old versions, just added ad units for rewarded ad and I call void for rewarded ad on the other scene... So technically banner codes are same. Any idea?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64299247/no-ad-config-on-onadfailedtoload-method-while-trying-to-load-ads